# Как проверить существует ли файл через PHP?

Tags: php, html, файлы

Вот моя проверка на логотип, если путь пуст, то логотипа не будет. Как сделать чтобы не было логотипа если путь указан неверно?

```
<?php if (!empty($config['logo'])): ?>                              
  <img src="<?= $config['logo']?>" class="" alt="logo">                             
<?php endif; ?>
```

Нужно проверить есть ли файл `$config['logo']` . Именно файла, проверка на пустое значение в `$config['logo']` уже есть

Comment: А как программа будет знать, правильный путь указан или нет? Что для неё значит правильно, а что нет?

Comment: Ну сайт ведь может проверить есть файл, или нет, может можно как-то сделать php запрос. Я вроде и задаю вопрос чтобы решить как-то его, при этом не зная ответа

Answer (score 2):

file_exists — Проверяет существование указанного файла или каталога

Проверка существования файла

```
<?
$filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "Файл $filename существует";
} else {
echo "Файл $filename не существует";
}
?>
```

is_readable() - Определяет существование файла и доступен ли он для чтения

is_writable() - Определяет, доступен ли файл для записи

is_file() - Определяет, является ли файл обычным файлом

file() - Читает содержимое файла и помещает его в массив

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if (!empty($config['logo']) && is_readable($config['logo'])): ?>
    <img src="<?= $config['logo'] ?>" class="" alt="logo">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Отдавать картинку потом может даже не апач, так что проверять на чтение в пхп не всегда имеет смысл